# Can I weak reference methods?

Tags: python, weak-references

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn't the weakref work on this bound method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599430/why-doesnt-the-weakref-work-on-this-bound-method)

A bit of context:

I was trying to implement an Listener (or Observer, same thing) pattern: An EventManager keeps a list of all the Listeners handlers interested in an Event.  For example, a Listener object would have a `onEndOfTheWorldEvent` method which would be called by the EventManager each time an instance of the event class EndOfTheWorldEvent is posted.  Easy.

Except that I wanted to weak reference the handlers because I don't want the EventManager to keep my handlers (bound methods) alive when the Listener was not needed anymore.

So I thought "Let's throw all the handlers in a WeakSet".  I couldn't get it to work.

I dump here the code (or what's left of it when I reduce it to the minimum, here there's only one type of event and only one type of handler).

```
#! /usr/bin/python
"""

"""
import sys
import weakref

class Listener(object):
    def handler(self, event):
        print event

class EventManager(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.handlers = weakref.WeakSet()
    def register(self, listener):
        print "Registering..."
        self.handlers.add(listener.handler)
        CountRefs(listener.handler)
        print "Number of handlers registered:", len(self.handlers)
        print "Registered."

def CountRefs(what):
    print "Hard count:", sys.getrefcount(what)
    print "Weak count:", weakref.getweakrefcount(what)

listener = Listener()
em = EventManager()
CountRefs(listener.handler)
em.register(listener)
CountRefs(listener.handler)
```

result:

```
Hard count: 3
Weak count: 0
Registering...
Hard count: 3
Weak count: 0
Number of handlers registered: 0
Registered.
Hard count: 3
Weak count: 0
```

It just looks like there's never any weak reference, and the set remains empty.

To make it even simpler:

```
>>> class C(object):
>>>     def blah(self):
>>>         print "blah"
>>> 
>>> c = C()
>>> w = weakref.ref(c.blah)
>>> print w
<weakref at 0x11e59f0; dead>
```

Can't I create weakrefs to methods at all ?  If not, **why not** ?

So I guess a workaround would be to replace the WeakSet with a WeakKeyDictionary: key is the listener itself, and value the handler.  Indeed I can weakref my Listeners.  But it makes the data structure a bit more complicated, and when comes the time to broadcast the events to everybody, there's one more level in that structure to go through.

What do you think ?

Comment: This question is not really duplicate, because it focuses on a solution and not just "why doesn't". Let alone the good accepted answer here. At best you can mark the other question as duplicate in the sense of: "this one implies the answer to the other".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's say you want weakrefs on a method "meth".

You can get weakrefs on it like this

```
weak_obj = weakref.ref(meth.im_self)
weak_func = weakref.ref(meth.im_func)
```

So, you can deref it like that

```
obj = weak_obj()
func = weak_func()
```

and get "meth" back with

```
meth = getattr(obj, func.__name__)
```

Comment: Wow, neat trick.  I never needed to look at these im_self and co before.

Comment: Actually, I needed that, because the bound method references the instance, and therefore the instance does not disappear from the WeakKeyDictionary.  Thanks !

Comment: Seems that from Python 2.6 moving forward the preferred access for these is `bound_method.__self__` for the object, and `bound_method.__func__` for the function.

Answer (score 2):

`listener.handler` gives you a new bound reference to the function each time. So it gets garbage collected almost immediately.

Comment: Indeed, the comparison with "is" always return False.  Then again I thought it could just have been a weird convention.

Comment: @Neil Could you please elaborate more on `listener.handler` and how to use it to give a new bound reference to a function? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @AhmedWas I'm not sure what you're asking. `listener.handler` is an expression that returns a function which invokes the original function (as declared in the class) but always bound to the given instance. It just happens that the expression works by giving you a new bound reference each time, which is unhelpful in the context of the original question.